# Cannot execute inserts querys after upgrade to mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, debian

I have Debian 8 (Jessie) server and i followed this procedure to upgrade from mysql 5.5 to mysql 5.7 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation-debian.html

Now, any script in the server that have an INSERT query is not working... The script is being executed but the INSERT query is returning always false with no error description...

Any ideas how to solve?

This is what i have installed 
[image]

Also, when i click on Database button in phpmyadmin

[image]

i'm getting this error

[image]

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW TABLE STATUS` and the `INSERT` query. Also look in the file `mysqld.err` .

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about #1055...

1055: `sql_mode` includes `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.  When doing a `GROUP BY`, you *should* include all the columns in the `SELECT` other than aggregates.

If your question is about `INSERT`, I don't see any supporting info.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem when i first upgraded to 5.7, i think strict sql mode is enabled by default and if you have tables with not null columns and no default value will behave like this.